# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{l-a} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a+x)^2-a^2}} $

Tags: definite-integrals

Willing to evaluate
 $$\int_{0}^{l-a} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a+x)^2-a^2} }$$

The answer is given $ \cosh ^{-1} (l/a)$. Don't know how this can be achieved.

Please help

Comment: Note that once you have the answer, you can check it by taking the derivative of both expressions with respect to $l$ (and checking the equality at one point—probably $l=a$ is best).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$\sqrt{x^2+2ax}=x+t$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{t^2}{2a-2t}$$ and $$dx=\frac{4at-2t^2}{(2a-2t)^2}dt$$
with the second line you Can express the term with the square root as a function in $t$
$$\sqrt{x^2+2ax}=t+\frac{t^2}{2a-2t}$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+2ax}=1/2\,{\frac {t \left( 2\,a-t \right) }{a-t}}
$$

Comment: I am little confused about why should we assume a function of x again as a function of x and t ?

Comment: This is the so-called Euler substitution

Comment: And what about the limit? I am getting a quadratic in t for $x=l-a$

Comment: For simplification you Can solve at first the indefinite integral